# Compare two table and find missing row

Tags: mysql, sql, teradata

I have two simple tables:

table1 :

```
id , h_id, role, l_name
1 , 2, 3, test1
1, 2, 4, test1
```

table2 :

```
id , h_id, role, l_name
1 , 2, 3, test1
1 , 2, 3, test2
```

we do not have any primary or foreign key to compare. there are chances that `id , h_id, role,` might have same data in both table but `l_name` could be different. it cloud be other column as well.

what is best way to compare for above scenario?

Comment: do a `union` that should give your unique data.

Comment: 2 separate queries with WHERE NOT EXISTS - first query searches the rows in table1 which are absent in table2, second one solves backward task. The presence of the composite index by long columns list (optimal - all columns used for comparing) will improve.

Comment: What's your expected result?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your case, you would be able to isolate data doesn't match from both table1 and table2 ? Is this ? So you can try this query :

```
select t1.id, t1.h_id,t1.role, t1.l_name, t2.id, t2.h_id,t2.role, 
  t2.l_name from table1 t1
left join table2 t2 
on t1.id = t2.id and t1.h_id =t2.h_id and t1.role=t2.role and   t1.l_name=t2.l_name
where t2.id is null
union
select t2.id, t2.h_id, t2.role, t2.l_name, t1.id, t1.h_id, t1.role, 
  t1.l_name from table1 t2
right join table2 t1
on t1.id = t2.id and t1.h_id = t2.h_id and t1.role=t2.role and t1.l_name = t2.l_name 
where t2.id is null;
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I would use the MINUS operator:

```
Select * from table1
Minus
Select * from table2
```

And repeat the other way